# Log in Form Using C# without database

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm using this Code For Log in form. The code running without error but not moving to next form

```
string a = textBox1.ToString();
string b = textBox2.ToString();

if (a == "admin" && b == "admin") {
    Form2 frm = new Form2();
    frm.Show();
    MessageBox.Show("Successfully Login");
} else {
    MessageBox.Show("Error");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have checked the `TextBox` control while you need to check for [`Text`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.text(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
string a = textBox1.Text;
string b = textBox2.Text;
```

Comment: Thanks Now It's Run Successfully. But If I'm Using String I don't need to convert it  into Tostring(); ????

Comment: @Fareed Property `TextBox.Text` is already a string, so converting `string` to `string` is pointless.

Comment: `textBox1.ToString()` returns textbox type name instead of text content. Use `Text` property to assign with actual text value.

Comment: @Fareed Values entered into textboxes are getting assigned to "Text" Propery of TextBox which is by default string only.

Comment: why we use Tostring();

Comment: @Fareed Read this about `ToString` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx